# confusion related to the dual of SVM

Tags: svm, optimization

I have a confusion related to the dual of SVM

In the main objective function I have:

$$\mathcal{L}(w,b,\xi,\alpha,r)=\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 +C\sum\limits_i \xi_i -\sum\limits_i \alpha_i\{ y^{(i)}(w^T x^{(i)}+ b) - 1 +\xi_i \} -\sum\limits_i r_i\xi_i$$

Now to solve the dual of this objective function, I will minimize with respect to the primal variables first to get:

$$w=\sum \alpha_i y^{(i)} x^{(i)} \\ \sum \alpha_i y^{(i)}=0 \\ \alpha_i = c - r_i \quad \forall i $$

I didn't get how substituting the value of $w$ in the lagrangian will give me:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j}\alpha_i\alpha_jy^{(i)}y^{(j)}{x^{(i)}}^Tx^{(j)}$$

Where did the minus sign come from in the above?

I got the other terms by substituting the remaining terms. But I didn't get the above term how it came to give me:

$$\max\limits_{\alpha \ge 0} \mathcal{L}(\alpha) = \sum\limits_i \alpha_i - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j} \alpha_i \alpha_j y^{(i)} y^{(j)} {x^{(i)}}^T x^{(j)} \\ \text{such that}\quad \sum\limits_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}=0 \\ 0 \le\alpha\le c \quad \forall i$$

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the Lagrangian, you have a term of  $-w^T \left(\sum_i \alpha_i y^{(i)}x^{(i)}\right)$ which is $-||w||^2$. Thus, you have a value of $-\frac{1}{2}||w||^2$. Substitute the value of $w$ back in to get the result.

Comment: Here is the step-by-step derivation of the regression case https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578076/derivation-of-the-svm-regression-problem