# Derivation of the SVM regression problem

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, optimization, svm, lagrange-multipliers

**EDIT**: The terms at the end will not get cancelled as they involve different variables: $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$, etc. Now the post is corrected. I will leave this question here in case someone is as dummy as me and finds this post in the future.

I am trying to derive SVM regression model step by step in order to understand it better. However there is one step I cannot understand at all: the moment in which the primal formulation is switched to dual formulation and the minus sign appears in front of a term. The Lagrange primal function that is to be minimized is given as follows:

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\lVert \textbf{w} \rVert^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^{p}(\xi_i+\xi^*)-\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\eta_i\xi_i+\eta_i^*\xi^*)+\\-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i(\varepsilon+\xi_i-y_i+\langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle+b)+\\-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*(\varepsilon+\xi_i^*+y_i-\langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle-b)$$
with $\alpha_i,\alpha_i^* \geq0$ and $\eta_i,\eta_i^* \geq0$ and $p$ being the size of the dataset.

And then the dual formulation is given:
$$\max_{\alpha, \alpha^*} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{p}y_i(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)-\varepsilon\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\alpha_i+\alpha_i^*) \color{red}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)(\alpha_j-\alpha_j^*)\langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle \right]$$
subject to $\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)=0$ and $\alpha_i,\alpha_i^* \in[0,C]$.

The problem I have is the minus sign (marked red) preceeding the last term. I've derived the formula many times and I always get the plus sign before it. I guess there is some trick with switching from primal to dual formulation which I am not aware of.

I've checked that in multiple sources (for example [A Tutorial on Support Vector Regression](https://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf)) and five books on ML I have and still found no answer. I've found a great post on the [problem of classification on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331931/lagrangian-dual-of-svm-derivation). However it did not help me to solve my problem.

My derivation is given below (skipping the derivation of the primal problem since I've got the same outcome):

- the derivatives of $L$ with respect to primal variables are:
  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \textbf{w}}=w-\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)x_i=0$$
  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}=\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i^*-\alpha_i)=0$$
  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \xi}=C-\alpha_i-\eta_i=0$$
  $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \xi^*}=C-\alpha_i^*-\eta_i^*=0$$
- Introducing $C-\alpha_i-\eta_i=0$ and $C-\alpha_i^*-\eta_i^*=0$ into $-\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\eta_i\xi_i+\eta_i^*\xi^*)$ yields
  $$-C\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\xi_i+\xi_i^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*$$
  step-by-step:
  $-\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\eta_i\xi_i+\eta_i^*\xi^*)=-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\eta_i\xi_i-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\eta_i\xi_i=-\sum_{i=1}^{p}(C-\alpha_i)\xi_i-\sum_{i=1}^{p}(C-\alpha_i^*)\xi_i^*=$
  $-C\sum_{i=1}^{p}\xi_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i-C\sum_{i=1}^{p}\xi_i^*+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*=$
  $-C\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\xi_i+\xi_i^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*$
- Expanding
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i(\varepsilon+\xi_i-y_i+\langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle+b)=\\ \varepsilon\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i y_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i \langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle+b\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i$$
  and
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*(\varepsilon+\xi_i^*+y_i-\langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle-b)=\\ \varepsilon\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^* y_i-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^* \langle\textbf{2},\textbf{x}_i\rangle-b\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*$$
- Using the fact that $\lVert \textbf{w} \rVert^2=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)(\alpha_j-\alpha_j^*)\langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle$ and introducing all above to the $L$ i get:
  $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)(\alpha_j-\alpha_j^*)\langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle+C\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\xi_i+\xi_i^*)+ \\ \color{blue}{-C\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\xi_i+\xi_i^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i+\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*}+ \\ -\color{green}{ \left(\varepsilon\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i\xi_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i y_i+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i \langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle+b\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i \right)}+\\
  -\color{orange}{\left( \varepsilon\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\xi_i^*+\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^* y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^* \langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle-b\sum_{j=1}^{p}\alpha_i^*\right)}$$

It is easy to notice that many terms will get cancelled due to opposite signs. Finally I get:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)(\alpha_j-\alpha_j^*)\langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle-\varepsilon\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\alpha_i+\alpha_i^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{p}y_i(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)+\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)\langle\textbf{w},\textbf{x}_i\rangle+b\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\alpha_i^*-\alpha_i)$$

Based on the derivative of $L$ with respect to $b$ the last term vanishes, and introducing relation for $\textbf{w}$ from the derivatives of L one gets the final solution with the minus sign.
$$\max_{\alpha, \alpha^*} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{p}y_i(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)-\varepsilon\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\alpha_i+\alpha_i^*) -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)(\alpha_j-\alpha_j^*)\langle\textbf{x}_i,\textbf{x}_j\rangle \right]$$
subject to $\sum_{j=1}^{p}(\alpha_i-\alpha_i^*)=0$ and $\alpha_i,\alpha_i^* \in[0,C]$.

Comment: substitute value of w. It will be 1/2() - 1() = -1/2()